# How to break on exception in my code at InteliJ

Tags: java, intellij-15

[image]I'm new to Java and using InteliJ Idea community edition.
I previously used Visual Studio with C#, where I could select if exception would break (and wait "as breakpoint") on my code only.

meaning I could choose to avoid seeing exceptions of 3rd party libraries, until (and only if) they affect my code.

At InteliJ Idea I could not find that option...
Only "stop at all exceptions" which is mostly to verbose for me

Comment: In the Breakpoints view (ctrl+shift+a for searching in actions->breakpoints) you should be able to click on a plus sign to add 'Java Exception Breakpoints' and there you can choose a type.
(This is on intellij ultimate though, but I would assume it's also available in community.)
(See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html).

Comment: I added a picture to the question. I don't know the type of the exception I want to catch, or the class that throws or catches it. Just that I want the code to break at the first line of code that's mine, showing only my code stack.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open "View Breakpoints".
   [image]
2. Add "Java Exception Breakpoints".

[image: 2]

3. Find the exception you want to keep track of.

   [image: 3]
4. Apply filters

[image]

There is no handy option to exclude/include the whole scope (e.g. your current project scope), but you may write a class pattern to filter out individual packages (e.g. `-java.* -sun.*`).

You also may play with the condition for hitting a breakpoint. It has the context of an exception itself (`this`) and, thus, `this.getStackTrace()` which can be used to determine what path, origin (`getStackTrace()[0]`), or destination (`getStackTrace()[getStackTrace().length - 1]`) to reject. It's not the best solution, but, at least, an option to consider.